# Detect double new lines with bash script

Tags: bash

I am attempting to return the line number of lines that have a break. An input example:

```
2938
383

3938
3

383
33333
```

But my script is not working and I can't see why. My script:

```bash
input="./input.txt"
declare -i count=0

while IFS= read -r line;
do
    ((count++))
    if [ "$line" == $'\n\n' ]; then
        echo "$count"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

So I would expect, `3, 6` as output.

I just receive a blank response in the terminal when I execute. So there isn't a syntax error, something else is wrong with the approach I am taking. Bit stumped and grateful for any pointers..

Also "just use awk" doesn't help me. I need this structure for additional conditions (this is just a preliminary test) and I don't know awk syntax.

Comment: Read reads only one line at a time. So `$line` will never contain `\n\n`.

Comment: @Cyrus could you please elaborate, lines 3 and 6 are clearly single lines and if I change `\n\n` to `$'3938'` it returns the line number (4)

Comment: Replace the `[ "$line" == $'\n\n' ]` with `[ -z "$line" ]` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `"$line" == $'\n\n'` won't match a newline as it won't be there after consuming an empty line from the input, instead you can match an empty line with regex pattern `^$`:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ ^$ ]]; then
```

Now it should work.

---

It's also match easier with `awk` command:

```
$ awk '$0 == ""{ print NR }' test.txt
3
6
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks this works. Could you tell me why `\n\n` wouldn't match a new line though?

Comment: @thomasbishop Because read stops at newline. IFS is only for splitting parts of the line.

Comment: @thomasbishop, `read` consumes each line using newline as separator/barrier and by default it removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, or any whitespace characters). When it gets to an empty line the `\n` won't be there (in `line`)

Comment: This makes much more sense now. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Roman suggested, line read by `read` terminates with a delimiter, and that delimiter would not show up in the line the way you're testing for.

If the pattern you are searching for looks like an empty line (which I infer is how a "double newline" always manifests), then you can just test for that:

```
while read -r; do
    ((count++))
    if [[ -z "$REPLY" ]]; then
        echo "$count"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Note that IFS is for field-splitting data on lines, and since we're only interested in empty lines, IFS is moot.

Or if the file is small enough to fit in memory and you want something faster:

```
mapfile -t -O1 foo < i
declare -p foo
for n in "${!foo[@]}"; do
  if [[ -z "${foo[$n]}" ]]; then
    echo "$n"
  fi
done
```

Reading the file all at once (`mapfile`) then stepping through an array may be easier on resources than stepping through a file line by line.

Comment: This is very helpful. I was not aware of `$REPLY`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use GNU awk:

```
gawk -v RS= -F '\n' '{ print (i += NF); i += length(RT) - 1 }' input.txt
```

Comment: @thomasbishop You're right. I also didn't understand your goal. I absorbed it as getting the last lines before break.

Comment: He wants the line numbers of the empty lines.

Comment: @Cyrus He wants the "double newlines" which may or may not exactly mean empty lines simply even though it turns out to be like it. If there are two or more consecuttive blank lines, which one is the double line? The problem was I tried to read the intent of the code (whuch I also wrongly did) instead of making sure I read all the description. I missed this: "So I would expect, 3, 6 as output.". Whether he wanted blank lines purely or "double lines" (which seems he meant as `$'\n\n'`) wouldn't have mattered.

Answer (score 0):

By using `FS = ".+"`, it ensures only truly zero-length (i.e. `$0 == ""`) line numbers get printed, while skipping rows consisting entirely of `[[:space:]]'s`

```
echo  '2938
       383

       3938
       3

       383
       33333' |
```

> ```
>  {m,g,n}awk -F'.+' '!NF && $!NF = NR'
> ```

```
3
6
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` one-liner should do the job at once:

```
sed -n '/^$/=' input.txt
```

Simply writes the current line number (the `=` command) if the line read is empty (the `/^$/` matches the empty line).